# Keras accuracy is not increasing over 50%

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to build a binary classification algorithm (output is 0 or 1) on a dataset that contains normal and malicious network packets.
The dataset shape (after converting IP @'s and hexa to decimal) is:
[IP src, IP dest, ports, TTL, etc..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX4HD.png)

Note: The final column is the output.

And the Keras model is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
seed = 4
numpy.random.seed(seed)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("NetworkPackets.csv", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:, 0:11].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:, 11]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5)

scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

However, I tried different optimizers, activation functions, number of layers, but the accuracy is reaching 0.5 at most:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8IZW.png)

Even I tried Grid search for searching the best parameters, but the maximum is 0.5.
Does anyone knows why the output is always like that? and how can I enhance it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answering these questions is entirely dependent on your data set and problem at hand. This question is ultimately more suited to data science or stats SE sites.

Comment: Yes I figured out that the problem maybe in my dataset, so I used `standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(X)` in order to recreate the dataset with a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1, the accuracy reached 0.97 which is great, but I do not feel that this is right!

Comment: @AhmadHijazi That is right, input/output normalization is quite important for NN training, in most cases nothing works without it.

Answer (score 1):

Your model isn't even outperforming a random chance model, so there must be something wrong in the data.
There may be two possibilities

1 - You don't feed enough training samples to your model for it to identify significant features as to distinguish between normal and malicious.

2 - The data itself is not informative enough to derive the decision you are looking for.

Comment: 1- I have a dataset of 200,000 packet, divided into normal and malicious, so I think there is enough samples for the model!
2- The data is easy one (same IPsrc and dest, same ports, almost same values) so I think the training will be easy for it.

Comment: But are you sure that just by looking at IPs and ports (etc) will be enough for a model to identify something as malicious or not?

Comment: The traffic is for a modbus network (communication protocol for transmitting information over serial lines between electronic devices) So the only change in the packets will be in the Modbus layer (function code, value, register, etc..) and those are included in the dataset.

Comment: I included an image for the dataset in the question

Comment: But what I am asking is if you know for a fact that just by looking at the data you added (IPs, etc) it is possible to determine if a comm is malicious or not. 


Having a lot of data isn't necessarily enough. The data must be descriptive for the answer you are trying to achieve. It would appear that the algorithm can't see any pattern in the data to determine a answer better then 50%, which is the same as if you added random data. 

If you are sure the data is descriptive, then the problem must lie somewhere in the implementation